# Is there an action for when permalinks are rebuilt?

Tags: permalinks, hooks, actions

In my plugin, I have a list of titles and permalinks in the options table. It's updated every time my custom post type is saved.

Since I'm saving permalinks the option data can become bad if the user changes their permalink structure.

I need a action that I can hook into that happens whenever the permalink structure is updated. Is there one?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The action is `update_option_permalink_structure`. You get the old and the new value as parameters.

```
add_action( 'update_option_permalink_structure' , 'my_custom_function', 10, 2 );

function my_custom_function( $oldvalue, $_newvalue )
{
    // do something
}
```

There are also the actions `update_option_category_base` and `update_option_tag_base`.

Comment: Worked great, and thanks for the additional information